# unable to fire local notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I am trying to fire local notification in my app and I am using the following the code -

```
-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

NSDate *alarmTime=[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:5.0];
UIApplication *app=[UIApplication sharedApplication];
UILocalNotification *notifiArea=[[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

if (notifiArea) {
    notifiArea.fireDate=alarmTime;
    notifiArea.timeZone=[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    notifiArea.repeatInterval=0;
    notifiArea.soundName=@"";
    notifiArea.alertBody=@"This is a push notification";
    [app scheduleLocalNotification:notifiArea];
  }
}


- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {

    UIApplication *app=[UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSArray *oldNotifications=[app scheduledLocalNotifications];
    if([oldNotifications count]>0){
           [app cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    }
   }
```

now when I'm debugging the app my alarm time is coming 2`017-04-24 11:27:51 +0000` but my simulator timing is `4:55pm`.

What is the problem?

Comment: did you check in ios 9 ?

Comment: scheduleLocalNotification deprecated in ios 10 .

Comment: You are getting different timing because of timezone

Comment: Your code is working on my device. I'm able to get the notification

Comment: Mostly the issue might be related to timezone. Use systemTimeZone and check. If you are not aware timezones. Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18424569/understanding-uilocalnotification-timezone

Comment: Concerns to timeZone. not a big deal

Comment: Small comment on your code, you don't need `UIApplication *app =[UIApplication sharedApplication];`, just use `application` that is passed in the method.

Answer (score 0):

After run the code have you gone to the home or screen lock in simulator.Date always taking current zone until we will set the another timezone.So if your alarm time is not matching with simulator time,Don't worry,This is not the issue it just showing.