# Notification Center and changing timezones

Tags: swift, swift4, unusernotificationcenter

**Swift 4 & >iOS 10.0**

I want to schedule a local notification at a certain date and at a given time (let's say 3PM). I want the notifications to always be fired at 3PM, whatever the timezone I am in (automatic rescheduling of notifications according to timezones).

Previously, you could tweak `UILocalNotifications`' time zone to achieve exactly this, like perfectly explained in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18424569/understanding-uilocalnotification-timezone). However, in `>iOS 10.0`, `UILocalNotifications` is deprecated.

Here is my code:

```
func scheduleNotification(title: String, message: String, atDate: Date){

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    // Create content
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = title
    content.body = message
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    // Create trigger
    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    let triggerDate = calendar.dateComponents([.year,.month,.day,.hour,.minute,.second,], from: atDate)
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDate, repeats: false)

    // Create identifier
    let identifier = "\(UUID())"

    // Create request & add to center
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier,
                                        content: content,
                                        trigger: trigger)
    center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: { (error) in
    })
  }
```

**Question:**
How do you make the notification triggers properly with changing timezones ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I managed to make it work. The `triggerDate` has a timeZone variable which is automatically nil, exactly like `UILocalNotification`.

`triggerDate.timeZone` behaves exactly like `UILocalNotification.timeZone` (behaviour described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18424569/understanding-uilocalnotification-timezone?noredirect=1&lq=1), the same as mentioned in the question).

One of the reason it did not seem to work on the simulator was because I was not restarting the simulator when changing the timezone. Restarting will make everything work as expected.

*Nota bene: Maybe a restart is not mandatory but since it's not obvious how much time a running simulator will take to detect the new timezone, I think restarting it is the most efficient solution.*

Comment: triggerDate is of type DateComponents ??

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. What exactly the value of triggerDate.timeZone?